# Error when routing to different page after signing in/retrieving document Firebase in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I started a new Vue 3 project with Vuex 4 and Firebase. I wanted to try out Firebase and Vue 3 (not yet with the composition-api) but I think I must be missing something somwhere.

I'm working on a sign up/in/out form through Firebase email/password authentication, but when signing in and retrieving the user details, I keep running into an error which breaks navigating to a different page. At first I thought this has to do with Vuex 4, but when moving the code to the login-component as a regular method, I get the same error (skipping Vuex entirely to test this).

Signing in actually works (I get the user data) and retrieving the profile data also works, but I get this error as soon as I try to redirect:

```
 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next 
  at <Home onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App> build.umd.js:2420

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: parent is null - runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:11
```

[image]

The login method:

```
        login() {
            // this.$store.dispatch('login', {
            //     email:    this.loginForm.email,
            //     password: this.loginForm.password
            // }).then(() => this.$router.push('/dashboard'))

            fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.loginForm.email, this.loginForm.password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    const user = userCredential.user;
                    if (user && user.uid) {

                        const ref = fb.usersCollection.doc(user.uid);
                        ref.get().then((doc) => {
                            if (doc.exists) {
                                // TODO save in vuex store
                                console.log(doc.data());
                                this.$router.push('/')
                            } else {
                                alert("No such document!");
                            }
                        });

                    }
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    alert(error.message);
                });
        },
```

No errors occur when I leave the `this.$router.push('/')` out (and `doc.data()` contains the data I need), but I need to redirect the user to his dashboard after logging in.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this? Must be something simple I'm overlooking.

I import the following file in the component (`import * as fb from "@/firebase";`):

```
/* eslint-disable */
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'

// firebase init
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey:            "X",
    authDomain:        "X.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId:         "X",
    storageBucket:     "X.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "123",
    appId:             "X",
    measurementId:     "X"
}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

// utils
const db   = firebase.firestore()
const auth = firebase.auth()

// collection references
const usersCollection    = db.collection('users')

// export utils/refs
export {
    db,
    auth,
    usersCollection,
}
```

Didn't want to post a demo-project online due to the API creds, but if needed, let me know and I'll see what I can do